# How to write subquery for same table n mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table called sample.

```
create table sample(name varchar(50),  amount int(10));

insert into sample(name,amount) values('rose',1000);
insert into sample(name,amount) values('jhon',2000);
insert into sample(name,amount) values('rose',2000);
insert into sample(name,amount) values('rahel',1000);
insert into sample(name,amount) values('rose',3000);
```

I want the output as,

```
+----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
+---rose---+--1000----+-------2000----+---3000----+
+---jhon---+--2000----+---------------+-----------+
+---rahel--+--1000----+---------------+-----------+
```

How to write the query for get the output likes above?

Comment: Let me guess. You don't know the number of `amount` per `name` in advance. And second it is only for presentation layer. Anyway search for `rows to columns`.

Comment: as i think your no. of column is dynamic ?if `rose` count is 4 then there will be amount1,amount 2,amount 3,amount 4 ........am i right??

Comment: yes..  no of column is dynamic @jordan

Answer (score 0):

you need to use group_concat(), the below query will give you the output

```
select name, group_concat(amount) from sample 
group by name
```

Comment: No,Group_concat will not work because group_concat convert them in a single column rather than multiple column as per count dynamically

Comment: @Jordan, what advantage would you get by the result being in multiple columns vs comma separated values, you can always split based on ','

Comment: look at the question and their expected result

Answer (score 0):

You want to pivot the values, but you don't have a column for pivoting.  You can assign a number using variables and then use conditional aggregation.  Assuming you want three additional columns:

```
select name,
       max(case when rn = 1 then amount end) as amount1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then amount end) as amount2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then amount end) as amount3
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from sample s cross join
           (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by name
     ) s
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **GROUP_CONCAT()** Function and your Query will be below mention:

select name,GROUP_CONCAT(amount) from sample 
group by name;

You will get your desire output.